# How to upload file directly to AWS S3 with AWS SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, file-upload

I want to upload image files directly to S3 without storing them on my server (for security). How can I do that with the [PHP SDK from AWS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) S3? here is an example code:

```php
<?php
require_once '/var/www/site/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = '<your bucket name>';
$keyname = 'sample';
$filepath = '/path/to/image.jpg';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'your AWS access key',
    'secret' => 'your AWS secret access key'
));

try {
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ));

    echo 'Success';
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Here is the upload form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

What would I put for `$filepath` in the PHP code since I don't want to store it on my server for security reason (I don't want it to execute malicious code and stuff like that)? Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Can you post the form/html where the image comes from?

Comment: @atymic yes I added that in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's built in file upload handling will make this very easy. When a request is received with a file, PHP automatically moves it to temporary location & makes it's metadata accessible using `$_FILES`.

You can then do something like below to upload the file to s3:

```php
<?php
if(empty($_FILES['image'])){
    die('Image missing');
}

$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tempFilePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'your AWS access key',
    'secret' => 'your AWS secret access key'
));

try {
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => '<your bucket>',
        'Key'    => $fileName,
        'SourceFile'   => $tempFilePath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ));

    echo 'Success';
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```